# how to separate text with multiple underscores and varying length of values

Tags: excel-formula, delimiter, separator

a1=ac_tree_birch_NewYork_ext

a2=bc_animal_dog_Washington_des

How do I separate the text in the cells by the "_", since there is varying length of the cell values. I would like to use a formula, and not text to columns.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at using `Flash Fill`

Comment: I'd prefer to use a formula. Any ideas about that?

Comment: You could use a combination of `IF`, `LEN`, `FIND`, `RIGHT`, `LEFT` and `SUBSTITUTE`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) to change all underscores (e.g. `CHAR(95)`) to a large number of spaces (typically the entire length of the original string) and peel out the padded pieces with the [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD). Finish off with [TRIM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) and an [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) 'wrapper'.

In B1 as,

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1, CHAR(95), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN($A1))), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*LEN($A1)+1, LEN($A1))), TEXT(,))
```

Fill both right and down.

[image: string_pieces]

Answer (score 2):

This can likely be done via `Flash Fill` (Excel 2013+).

For the first row of data, enter your expected outcome in subsequent cells to the right. This is how you want the data broken up:

[image]

Then select your first cell of output data and click Flash Fill from the ribbon:

[image]

Do this for the remaining columns.  This will fill the column based on the pattern recognized by Excel within your original data:

[image]

Comment: It probably should be noted somewhere that [Flash Fill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Flash-Fill-3fb96b4a-ee83-4493-af45-6522324477bd) was introduced with xl2013.

Comment: Thanks @jeeped, added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

If a VBA solution is acceptable, you can write a wrapper around the VBA `Split` function:

```
Public Function Split2(s As String) As String()
    Split2 = Split(s, "_")
End Function
```

Then in your worksheet, select (say) cells B1:F1, enter

```
=Split2(A1)
```

as an array function (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER), and out comes your data.

Hope that helps.