# Flashfill sample pattern improvement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want text in `column A` to be seperated into adjacent columns removing underscore. For this I used Flashfill (Excel 2013+) after entering sample pattern with the largest string in `Row A1`. Results are not as per my requirement as per image appended that is extra words as highlighted in the shaded portion should not appear and cells should be empty.
I am getting correct and desired results following a formula suggested by @Jeeped which are shown in another picture appended. I know that I can also get correct results in VBA with Split function.
I need help as how I can get correct results with Flashfill. What sample pattern to choose or what type of care to be taken to get desired results.

[image: Flashfill results]
[image]

Comment: If you have 2 options that work already, why do you need a Flash Fill solution?  Note that your data in column A *isn't* all the same pattern - "foo_bar_baz" isn't in the same pattern as "foo_bar".

Comment: @comintern In one of the questions on this site Flashfill was suggested for a similiar situation. I want to fully exploit the features offered by this feature. Hence interested in knowing the limitations and functionalities offered by this feature. Another point is that I may me missing something here which an advanced user or expert help me in locating.

Comment: If you're referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36228039/4088852), you should note that the number of underscores in the sample data were the same.

Comment: @Comintern In the referred answer no such limitation has been cautioned and the OP question title is broad enough. However if I accept your view point then it limits usefulness of this feature seriously.

Comment: @Comintern I have referred many related articles in the intervening period and have come to conclusion that this feature is quite useful for similar pattern situations like hyphening telephone numbers, extracting user names from email-IDs, first and last names etc. It is not suitable for the situation depicted by me here. I am prepared to accept your view point. You can put is an answer, If you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FEATURES:**

Flash Fill is a new feature introduced in Excel 2013.  Flash Fill typically starts working when it recognizes a pattern in your data, and works best when your data has some consistency.
Some of the most time consuming and irritating aspects of Excel are working with repetitive information. This included writing formulas, formatting, separating dates, and entering names and email addresses manually. Fortunately, the Flash Fill feature introduced with Microsoft Excel’s 2013 edition makes these tasks easier with brilliant automatic filling.

Excel’s Flash Fill is a time-saving feature which fills in data for you when a pattern is evident. It can also can extract and insert as well as format and concatenate. This feature can even reverse text, numbers, dates and much more.

**EXAMPLES**

Some examples are illustrated below.
Concatenating Last Name and First Name with Comma Separation.

[image: Concatenating names]

With the Flash fill feature, extracting text before the @ symbol from email addresses is simple.

[image: Concatenating names]

Type in the phone number format that you would like to use and Flash Fill will notice the pattern. You’ll also get options to Undo Flash Fill, Accept suggestions and Select all changed cells.

[image: Formatting Phone Numbers]

**Limitations and care to be taken while using Flash Fill**

Flash Fill doesn’t take into account changes in data. Say for example that you have used Flash Fill to combine first name and last name into a single full name column. If you make any changes to the names in the original columns, they will not be reflected in the combined column.
When using the flash fill feature, the data column that is referenced can be non-adjacent as long as there is contiguous column data between the column that is flash filled and the referenced column. Basically, this means that you cannot have an empty or blank column between the column that is being flash filled and the column whose values are being referenced. In this case, Excel will display a message box that informs you that it cannot find a pattern in the adjacent data.

***CONCLUSION:***
Situation depicted by me in this case appears to have consistent pattern but of being variable number of words is not suitable for Flash Fill

References:
[Excel 2013 Flash Fill anticipates needs on the fly](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/excel-2013-flash-fill-anticipates-needs-on-the-fly/)

[How to use Flash Fill in Excel 2013](http://www.businessproductivity.com/how-to-use-flash-fill-in-excel-2013/)

[A Beginner’s Guide to Flash Fill in Microsoft Excel 2013](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/48997/a-beginners-guide-to-flash-fill-in-microsoft-excel-2013/)